# Python program to write data in csv depends on column existence

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to append values in csv(already exist) with python programming, if the column already exists, it should be replaced or if the data is new I need to append it in the same file

What I tried so far:

csv data:

```
 SnapshotId,promotion level
 1.9.0.0,Tested
 2.0.0.1,Unit tested
```

Initial just appending (it works):

```
 with codecs.open('sample.csv','a',encoding='utf8') as newFile:
 newFileWriter = csv.writer(newFile)
 newFileWriter.writerow([str(snapshot_id),str(unitTest)])
```

So later my requirement changes like if incoming data like snapshotid already exist I should update the respective row value with promotion level, if snapshot id is unique and doesn't exist, I should then append a new row with snapshot id and promotion level.

I just tried like this with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import os,sys 
snapID = sys.argv[1]
promLevel = sys.argv[2]
df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
def update_table(snapID, promLevel):

if snapID in df['SnapshotId']:
    print("Updating promotion level")
    df.loc[df['SnapshotId'] == snapID, ['promotion_level']] = promLevel
else:
    print("Adding new snapshot")
    return df.append({'SnapshotId': snapID, 'promotion_level': promLevel}, ignore_index=True)
return df

   dd = update_table(str(snapID),promLevel)
   print(dd)
```

I can able to locate the index but am not sure how to check if column already exists and replace the whole row with new values in csv any insights would be great help

Comment: If I understand your question thoroughly you need to use Database instead of file system, In file system you can append a content from existing file but you can't update the value. If you want to update then you need to save as a new file using `to_csv`. But Many of the database provides functionality what you requires :-)

Comment: What you said is absolutely right as its easily doable in database but there are third party applications already using this file so am restricted to more changes

Comment: When you wanna update a file read the latest csv file you already written, then make changes in the current df(which you read as a csv). then apply to_csv without append argument. So that you make sure your file has updated value without losing your data

Comment: Exactly that would be final move if nothing works.i hope i wont have any data loss or duplicate values

Comment: The only way to "update" a file is rewriting it just like @MohamedThasinah explained. Read the dataframe, update it and rewrite the csv. There won't be any data loss or duplicated values if you code it wisely. I can post an answer with the code if you would like me to. This will only work if you make sure those third party applications also update their buffer. If they have the file somehow cached you will have to think things through.

Comment: Thanks khabz,would be great if u can help me a bit here i will post the code what i already tried here                 snapshotid_exist = (data['SnapshotId'] == '1.9.0.0').any()
if snapshotid_exist:
 data.loc['0','SnapshotId'] = '2.3.8';
 data.loc['0','promotion level'] = 'Rejected';
 data.reset_index(drop=True)

Comment: Ok so if I got it right, your program receives an input `(SnapshotID,promotion_level)`. If `SnapshopID` doesn't exist, append the new row to the datame. If it does, update `promotion_level` with the new value. Is this it?

Comment: yes exactly, am trying to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below reads a csv file, looks for a `snapshotId`. If it exists, the promotion level is replaced with the new value, otherwise a new row is appended:

```
def update_table(snapID, promLevel):

    # Reading file
    df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

    if df['SnapshotId'].str.contains(snapID).any():
        # Updating promotion level
        df.loc[df['SnapshotId'] == snapID, ['Promotion_Level']] = promLevel
        return df
    else:
        # Adding new snapshot
        return df.append({'SnapshotId': snapID, 'Promotion_Level': promLevel}, ignore_index=True)

# Updating original file
update_table('id01', 'P10').to_csv('file.csv')
```

A working example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'SnapshotId': [1,2,3,4,5],
    'Promotion_Level': ['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def update_table(snapID, promLevel):

    #df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

    if df['SnapshotId'].str.contains(snapID).any():
        # Updating promotion level
        df.loc[df['SnapshotId'] == snapID, ['Promotion_Level']] = promLevel
        return df
    else:
        # Adding new snapshot
        return df.append({'SnapshotId': snapID, 'Promotion_Level': promLevel}, ignore_index=True)


# Original df
0           1              P1
1           2              P2
2           3              P3
3           4              P4
4           5              P5

> print(update_table(1, 'a'))
0           1               a
1           2              P2
2           3              P3
3           4              P4
4           5              P5

> print(update_table(10, 'a'))
0           1              P1
1           2              P2
2           3              P3
3           4              P4
4           5              P5
5          10               a
```

Comment: Thank much @khabz here is the output btw    C:\Users\320047585\Sathish\Python\sample>python panda.py 1.9.0.0 sampling
here
  SnapshotId promotion_level
0    1.9.0.0        Rejected
1    2.0.0.1     Unit tested
2    1.9.0.0        sampling

Comment: it just got appened rather than replaced

Comment: everytime it enters else condition

Comment: Your code/output is not readable at all. To insert code in comments check this link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74784/how-do-i-add-code-while-writing-comments

Comment: yes i did it like this dd = update_table(str(snapID),promLevel)
print(dd)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention, the `value in list` condition only works for integer values, that's why the condition is never met. I will update the code in a second.

Comment: I have updated the code. Should work now @Sathishkumar

Comment: Not a problem!!